# Is live patching now available for HWE kernels?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Since live patching has been released only LTS kernels were supported with a note that live patching for HWE is in the works and likely to be available in 2017. I thought there would be an announcement when HWE support is ready but I must have missed it. I'm certain that there was no support for the 17.04 based HWE kernel, but I had to use mainline kernels for a while on this machine in the past months.

I just installed 4.13.0-16.19~16.04.3-generic through `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` but I'm not exactly sure if this kernel is supported by `canonical-livepatch`:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
client-version: "7.23"
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
last-check: 2017-11-08T21:16:29.971688844+01:00
boot-time: 2017-11-08T19:16:12+01:00
uptime: 2h54m26s
status:
- kernel: 4.13.0-16.19~16.04.3-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""
```

How do I know if a kernel is supported? Is there a support or wiki page where I can look this up? Or did someone find a URL in their networking logs showing some kind of hierarchy where these updates are fetched from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HWE Kernels **are supported** by `canonical-livepatch`.  In the link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack#Kernel_Livepatching at the bottom it states:

> For clarity, the Canonical Livepatch Service is only available and
> supported against the generic and lowlatency GA kernel flavours for
> 64-bit Intel/AMD (aka, x86_64, amd64) builds of the Ubuntu 16.04
> (Xenial) and 18.04 (Bionic) LTS releases.

*`canonical-livepatch` only supports the running kernel at the time and will not patch any other kernels that are installed on the system unless you reboot to the desired kernel.*

When you install a HWE kernel, you install a `generic` kernel, i.e. `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.  However, not all generic kernels are supported by `canonical-livepatch`.  Through a test of my own I installed a [mainline kernel](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) of 5.11 (I know it is the newest but it was just to show that it is unsupported).

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 23 minutes ago
kernel: (unsupported)
```

On my 20.04 LTS installation I have both the default kernel of 5.4x installed as well as the HWE 5.8x.  When checking the `canonical-livepatch` against them they both show the same output other than the kernel version.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 17 seconds ago
kernel: 5.4.0-65.73-generic
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux terrance-ubuntu 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 27 seconds ago
kernel: 5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux terrance-ubuntu 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy linux-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
  Installed: 5.8.0.43.49~20.04.29
  Candidate: 5.8.0.43.49~20.04.29
  Version table:
 *** 5.8.0.43.49~20.04.29 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like kernel live patching for hwe-edge is supported at the moment:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
client-version: "7.23"
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
last-check: 2017-11-22T01:02:00.691553956+01:00
boot-time: 2017-11-08T19:16:12+01:00
uptime: 318h15m52s
status:
- kernel: 4.13.0-16.19~16.04.3-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""

$ ll /boot/vmlinuz-4.13*generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7649456 Okt 16 23:17 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 7656048 Nov  6 17:16 /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-17-generic
```

Or that there is really nothing worth to patch at the moment, not sure though when looking at the respective [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-edge/linux-hwe-edge_4.13.0-17.20~16.04.1/changelog) via packages.ubuntu.com.

Edit: 4.10 kernels probably received a patch in the last hours, 4.13 is not listed in the latest USNs:

- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3485-2/
- https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3484-2/

Answer (score 1):

HWE kernel is not supported, see [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack#Kernel_Livepatching).

It says:

> For clarity, the Canonical Livepatch Service is only available and supported against the generic and lowlatency GA kernel flavours for 64-bit Intel/AMD (aka, x86_64, amd64) builds of the Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and 18.04 (Bionic) LTS releases.

updated @ 19.05.13

Comment: HWE is installed as a generic kernel so it is supported.