# Live patch disable when updating Ubuntu 22.04.1 kernel

Tags: kernel

Good evening, I want to know if there is a solution, I already have mainline kernel installed. If there is a kernel above version 6.0.0 or the live patch works I'm interested.

I don't like it being disabled with a newer version. For the moment I have an AMD radeon rx6800 nitro+ and I plan to buy an rx 7900xt. All I need is that as a prerequisite for it to be compatible, the LLVM and MESA are up to date.

thank you!

Comment: Live patch only works with LTS supported kernels.  When you are using mainline Kernels Live Patch does not support them at all.  You are welcome to file bugs against the kernel when you find it helping developers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is live patching now available for HWE kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974462/is-live-patching-now-available-for-hwe-kernels)

Comment: So how long should I wait to buy the RX 7900 XT before kernel 5.15.0.58-generic is compatible?

Are generic kernels updated?

Thanks !

Comment: You should be able to use that card with the drivers:  https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-rx-7000-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900xt

Answer (score 0):

So why does he say that on so many forums ?

[What is said on the same forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXLh.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).